# How to make select drop down list read only and unchangeable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, drop-down-menu

Here is a link of js fiddle

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/7Lcf533c/1/][1]
```

i make select dropdown read only but when i click on it it shows me the drop down option which should not show and it is changeable

Can you suggest a solution and update that in jsfiddle

Comment: Your question needs a [mcve]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

use `disabled` attribute

```
 <div class="col-sm-8"><select class="form-control" id="id_messageKindId" name="messageKindId" disabled="disabled" required="required" readonly="">
<option value="1">Appointment Reminder</option>
<option value="2">Eyeware or Contact Arrival</option>
<option value="3">Appt Delay / Move Up</option>
<option value="4">Appt Cancellation</option>
<option value="5">Recall</option>
<option value="7">After Appointment</option>
<option value="10" selected="selected">Pre Appointment</option>
<option value="11">Lab Results</option>
<option value="12">Collection Message</option>
<option value="13">Custom Message</option>
</select></div>
```

fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/7Lcf533c/5/

Comment: The `disabled` attribute will prevent value to be submited. So even if the field is unchangeable it will not work properly.

Comment: OP doesn't have mentioned that in the requirement. Though, that might be something desirable.

Comment: The OP didn't expressed the problem properly anyways (typical from new comers on SO). I didn't down voted the answer by the way, just pointed out that it'd have some collateral using your approach.

Comment: It would be useful to know about the downvote reason.

Comment: Probably because this isn't a [well-asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question and also because your answer doesn't have much quality. You can find some good tips looking on high scored users and checking the help center in [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). You are a `4k+` scored user, people won't forgive you for answring "bad questions" and answering it badly, a lot of people take SO policies very serios so they assume you should've known the good practices, it happens.

Comment: But, what you can do is, improve both the question and your answer and I'd be happy to give you an up-vote on that and I believe the down-voters would review your answer and perhaps remove the down vote if quality has improved.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#id_messageKindId option").prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: The options are not selectable, but your user can still see what options are available. If you don't want this then there is a much simple solution. Add this attribure to your dropdown: `disabled="disabled"`